# How can I get only the Store View attributes, without the inherited Global data? I only need the diffs

Tags: product, api, product-attribute, collection, magento-1

I'm using the internal Magento APIs to get the product data on a store view level. I only want to get the values that are on that store view level, not the global values that in inherits. But it returns all the values for all the fields, so I don't know which ones are the Global values and which are the Store View values. Is there a way to do this? If not with the APIs, then with SQL?

**UPDATE: As requested, I've pasted the code we're using, below:**
*--Mitch*

```
const PRODUCT_TYPE_CODE = 'catalog_product';
​
private function getProductPage($storeId, $pageId, $productsOnPage)
{
    $productData = array();
​
    $entityTypeId = LegacyHelperFunctions::getEntityIdByTypeCode(self::PRODUCT_TYPE_CODE);
​
    Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeId);
​
    $storeLastPageId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_type_id', $entityTypeId)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setPageSize($productsOnPage)
        ->getLastPageNumber();
​
    if ($storeLastPageId < $pageId) {
        return array();
    }
​
    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
        ->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_type_id', $entityTypeId)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->setPageSize($productsOnPage)
        ->setCurPage($pageId);
​
    foreach ($collection as $product) {
        $stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')
            ->loadByProduct($product->getEntityId());
​
        $usedAttributes = null;
        $configurableAttributesData = null;
        $usedSimpleProducts = null;
​
        if ($product->getTypeId() === 'configurable') {
            $usedAttributes = $product->getTypeInstance()
                ->getUsedProductAttributeIds();
​
            $configurableAttributesData = $product->getTypeInstance()
                ->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray();
​
​
            $usedSimpleProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                ->getChildrenIds($product->getId());
        }
​
        $productAttributeData = CustomArrayHelpers::except(
            $product->getData(), array(
                'website_ids',
                'store_ids',
                'category_ids',
                'attribute_set_id',
                'type_id',
                'entity_type_id',
                'entity_id',
                'image',
                'small_image',
                'thumbnail'
            )
        );
​
        if (!isset($productData[$product->getId()])) {
            $productData[$product->getId()] = array(
                'store_ids' => $product->getStoreIds(),
                'website_ids' => $product->getStoreIds(),
                'category_ids' => $product->getCategoryIds(),
                'attribute_set_id' => $product->getAttributeSetId(),
                'product_id' => $product->getEntityId(),
                'type_id' => $product->getTypeId(),
                'data' => array(),
                'stock' => $stockItem->getData(),
                'relations' => array(
                    'cross_sell' => $product->getCrossSellLinkCollection()->toArray(),
                    'up_sell' => $product->getUpSellLinkCollection()->toArray(),
                    'related' => $product->getRelatedLinkCollection()->toArray(),
                    'associated' => array(
                        'simple_products' => $usedSimpleProducts,
                        'attributes' => $usedAttributes,
                        'attribute_data' => $configurableAttributesData
                    )
                ),
                'images' => array(
                    'base_image' => $product->getImageUrl(),
                    'small_image' => $product->getSmallImageUrl(),
                    'thumbnail_image' => $product->getThumbnailUrl(),
                    'media_gallery' => $product->getMediaGalleryImages()
                )
            );
        }
​
        $productData[$product->getId()]['data'][$storeId] = array_merge($productAttributeData, array(
                'image' => $product->getImageUrl(),
                'small_image' => $product->getSmallImageUrl(),
                'thumbnail' => $product->getThumbnailUrl())
        );
    }
​
    return $productData;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the code you're using to get the product data ?

Comment: You will have to do it in SQL, the Magento API always uses the inheritance mechanism. Look up the values in `catalog_product_entity_{varchar,int,decimal,price,datetime,gallery,text}` with `WHERE store_id=X`

Answer (score 0):

To me I think using `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($storeId);` is not enough to retrieve store specific data.

I reckon you should update your collections code and add the following:

```
->addStoreFilter($storeId)
```

Comment: This won't help either to get only the overridden values and not the inherited values.